# How can I persist class state when using image_picker?

Tags: flutter

I have below code in flutter:

```
class PostingState extends State {

TextEditingController _messageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this._messageController = new TextEditingController();
  }

  void dispose() {
    this._messageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

_selectImage(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      developer.log('image path $image');
      this.setState(() => {images.add(image)});
    } catch (err) {
    }
  }


...

    TextField(
                              controller: this._messageController,
                              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              maxLines: null,
```

`ImagePicker.pickImage` will open image gallery and ask users to select a photo. It works fine and I am able to get the selected image. However, after finish selecting the photo in gallery, the text in the `TextField` becomes empty. How can I save the text in TextField?

Comment: You can refer this solution for it https://stackoverflow.com/a/61389154/3946958

Comment: That post is a different question. I don't have problem on selecting photos. My issue is how to save the TextField text after selecting image

Comment: The most possible cause is messageController is declared in build. when setState, cause rebuild and messageController reset it's value.

Comment: @chunhunghan You are pointing right, it might be the problem of eempty value

Comment: I have added the code about messageController. It is declared in class level.